# 'TCCR0B' undeclared

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, compilation-errors

I am trying to compile the function in http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency

This produces a couple of errors

```
sketch/setPwmFrequency.c:34:3: error: unknown type name 'byte'
   byte mode;
   ^
sketch/setPwmFrequency.c:45:7: error: 'TCCR0B' undeclared (first use in this function)
       TCCR0B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | mode;
```

`byte` is trivial, but I can't seem to find `TCCR0B` et al I assume it should be defined somewhere.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code, not just snippets. Minimal means you've stripped away irrelevant stuff, just leaving what's needed to show the problem. Complete means all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant. Verifiable means it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem

Comment: Other that missing setup() and loop(), that code compile OK with Arduino IDE 1.8.5 and UECIDE 0.9.1

Comment: @LookAlterno How can a verbatim download of the code from the link to the Arduino site be insufficient?

Comment: Insufficient because the link is not the whole picture. It's missing other things that you added. And this kind of problem is all about how do you arrange your sources. Yesterday I had a problems like yours and the solution was ... rename eeprom.ino to Eeprom.ino. Would you believe that? That is why we need your complete sketch.

Comment: Your chip doesn't have that register. Find out what the original code does and implement the same functionality on the target chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both errors can be solved by adding the following line to your setPwmFrequency.c:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
```

This will include the files that contain the `byte` typedef and also the register definitions.

You may notice that is not necessary in an .ino file. The reason is that the Arduino IDE automatically adds the Arduino.h include to .ino files during sketch preprocessing before compilation.

Comment: The #include partially solved the problem, but still didn't link. Maybe I could have solved with a `.h` file. I gave in to the dark side, and renamed it `.ino`. Life would be so much easier if Arduino didn't try to redefine c/c++ - particularly when the language seems to have changed since I last used it.

Comment: I assumed you would have a .h file to go with your .c file. I did my testing with that setup and it did indeed compile. The Arduino IDE really doesn't mess with the language much. Pretty much the only thing other than the automatic Arduino.h include in .ino files is it generates function prototypes in .ino files where necessary but you can manually declare them if you like. `main()` is hidden away in the core library but that's still standard c++.